# Journal Springer nature 2021 latex template and proof environment

Tags: pdftex, amsthm, proof-package, springer

I am using the latex template of Springer Nature from [here](https://www.springernature.com/gp/authors/campaigns/latex-author-support). Even though `\usepackage{amsthm}` is defined,
`\begin{proof ... \end{proof}` is not recognized and gives this error:

```
Missing $ inserted. \end{proof}
```

Here is the document class  [sn-jnl.cls](https://gist.github.com/sepideha/1e59f68dd24bd9f973ae9bcf49ce04ee)

The minimal complete code:

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical    Sciences Reference Style

\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
%\newtheorem{proof}{Proof} %Error: Command \proof already defined. \newtheorem{proof}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{lemma}
    Lemma is here. 
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof} %Error: Missing $ inserted. \end{proof}
    proof is here.
\end{proof}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for even a reasonable guess.  While it would probably be enough to post the text of the proof that is being complained about (you know that `\begin{proof}` has been read, or it would have stopped somewhere else), it would be much better to provide a brief compilable example, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that demonstrates the problem.  Just the preamble and the troublesome proof might be enough, and you might even find the problem yourself while creating such an example.

Comment: @barbarabeeton
Added the complete code with the error messages

Comment: I found a workaround also!

Comment: Erh, if I download that exact bundle from the link provided the `sn-article.tex` example compiles just fine, and it uses the `proof` env. Note that if `amsthm` is loaded they disable proof and you need to use `spiproof` instead.

Comment: I tried `\begin{spiproof}...\end{spiproof} ` didn't work and gives the same error as above.

Comment: I get no error.

Comment: Thanks. I disabled all the other packages like `\usepackage{filecontents,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}`and now it works with  `\begin{proof ... \end{proof}`

Comment: @sepideha please post your log of your compilation of the exact example above

Comment: Sorry cannot reproduce it anymore as I updated many things. But the error log When I add \usepackage{tikz} to the above example is as follows: ``(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.908 ...eoperator{||}{or}        {2}{infix} {200}``

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @daleif using `\proof` command instead of using the proof environment is not a good solution.

As the journal manual recommends`\begin{spiproof}...\end{spiproof}` works, make sure other packages not causing issues.

Comment: This is not a good solution. Using `proof` as an environment is directly stated in the provided user manual.

Comment: Thanks for reminding this!